# How can I get a list of domain names I own through Google Domains via PHP? Is there an API I can use?

Tags: php, google-domain-api

I am looking for a way to programmatically retrieve a list of domains that I own through Google Domains (domains.google.com).  I have found APIs available for Google *Cloud* Domains and Google Domains *RDAP* but these do not appear to be hooked into my Google Domains account, as when I make the API calls nothing is returned.

Has anyone found a way to do this?  I am specifically going to be using PHP but if someone can just point me to the correct API (and possibly documentation) to use?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reach Google Domains support regarding if there is an API I can use to export a list of registered domains with our account, and the response was "At the moment, we do not have that feature with Google Domains."

Answer (score 0):

GET [https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/{customer}/domains](https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/customer/%7Bcustomer%7D/domains)

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/reference/rest/v1/domains/list

you can check your all domains with your workspace customer-id with this GET API

Comment: [Link only answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) are considered very low quality and [can get deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), please put the important parts from the linked resource into the answer body.

Comment: This API is for Google Workspace and lists domains associated with the workspace. OP is asking for Google Domains which is a different service.